# Chemical spontaneity is characterized by $\Delta G<0$. Why is nuclear spontaneity characterized by $Q>0$ and not $\Delta G<0$ as well?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, nuclear-physics

Chemical reactions that occur at constant temperature and pressure are spontaneous if and only if the reaction reduces the systems Gibbs free energy ($\Delta G=\Delta H -T\Delta S<0$). Clearly this criterion permits spontaneous endothermic chemical reactions provided that the entropy of the system increases by enough (provided $T\Delta S >\Delta H$).

In my nuclear physics textbook (Krane) however, the author characterizes the emission of nuclear matter from a large nucleus (as in alpha decay) as being spontaneous only if the decay satisfies $Q=\Delta K >0$ where $\Delta K$ is the net kinetic energy released. Thus the $Q$ value of a nuclear decay seems to correspond to the change in enthalpy of the decay(so we should expect that $Q=\Delta H$). If this is the case then why do we not have an additional term of the form $-T\Delta S$ in the criterion for nuclear spontaneity? After all, alpha decay is occurring at constant temperature and pressure and in these conditions, $\Delta G <0$ is equivalent to $\Delta S_{universe}>0$. The fact that nuclear spontaneity is characterized by $Q>0$ seems to indicate that for some reason (?) endothermic nuclear reactions are impossible yet endothermic chemical reactions are. Why is this the case? Why do we not use $\Delta G<0)$ to characterize spontaneity of alpha emission?

Any help on this would be most appreciated!

Comment: The $\Delta G<0$ criterion for spontaneity is just a very crude "rule of thumb," indicating merely that the equilibrium constant is greater than 1.

Comment: @ChetMiller You might want to elaborate on the term 'equilibrium constant'.

Comment: Temperature is not relevent for nuclear decays. At room temperature $k_BT= 1/40$ eV and the energy spacing (in the order of keV) between nuclear levels is much greater than that, so the nucleus is always in it's ground state.

Comment: @mikestone What about entropy?

Comment: @Gert Entropy is irrelevent at $T=0$.  What does play a role in computingthe lifetimes of unstable nuclei  is the phase space volume available to the decay products. This is always positive, however, if the KE of the decay products is positive.

Answer (score 1):

> Chemical reactions that occur at constant temperature and pressure are
> spontaneous if and only if the reaction reduces the systems Gibbs free
> energy ($ΔG=ΔH−TΔS<0$). Clearly this criterion permits spontaneous
> endothermic chemical reactions provided that the entropy of the system
> increases by enough (provided $TΔS>ΔH$).

That's a very simplistic view of things.

Let's say we have a simple chemical equilibrium:

$$\mathrm{A}\leftarrow\rightarrow \mathrm{B}\tag{1}$$

The 'tendency' of this equilibrium to lean to the left or to the right depends on the equilibrium constant $K$:

$$K=\frac{[B]}{[A]}$$

where the bracketed quantities are (somewhat simplified) concentrations. Obviously if $K\gg 1$ then the reaction leans very much to the left (because $[B]\gg[A]$) but $K \ll 1$ then it leans much to the left.

$K$ relates to $\Delta G$ through:

$$\Delta G=-RT\ln K$$

So, very negative $\Delta G$ lead to large $K$ and the equilibrium leaning to the right of $(1)$.

Note also that *thermodymamics says nothing about kinetics*: a reaction may have a very high $K$, yet proceed at imperceptibly small rate.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! I guess my follow up question would then be why the spontaneity of nuclear decay depends only on the net kinetic energy released and not at all on the entropy of the products? Say our nucleus emits an alpha particle and the Q value  of the decay is $Q=Q_o>)$. If we now instead consider a nucleus that emits 2 separate protons and 2 separate neutrons all at once instead of one alpha particle with a Q value of $0<Q_1<Q_o$ . Clearly the entropy increase in the second example is greater than the first. Why does this greater $\Delta S$ not play any role in determining

Comment: spontaneity? Why is it *only* the amount of kinetic energy released that determines the spontaneity in a nuclear reaction and not a combination of the entropy change and energy release as is the case in chemical reactions?

Comment: @SalahTheGoat Hi! I have to owe you the answer to these questions (which are interesting!)  I'm a humble chemist, not a nuclear physicist. But I look forward to *someone else grasping the nettle* (of entropy in nuclear reactions)

Comment: The issue with entropy comes from the fact that, under most imaginable conditions, multiple nuclei are not in any sort of thermodynamic equilibrium - the possible phase space is highly limited. Coupled with there only being a small (really small) amount of entropy to be had by splitting into 2 or 3 pieces in only a few ways, entropy just doesn’t make a dent compared with the keV or MeV of enthalpy. (Nuclear thermodynamics might enter in reaction in various stages in a supernova?)